# What is the difference between an NSWindow and an NSView?

Tags: objective-c

I've looked and I can't see the difference... I know you use UIViews in IPhone dev a lot more than you use UIWindows and vice-versa in Mac OS X dev. Can someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are quite different.  You can display multiple NSViews within an NSWindow.

Comment: Oh, so an NSWindow is like a container for NSViews?

Comment: Yeah, that's one of it's main functions, but it really is a physical Mac OS window; defined by a frame rectangle that encloses the entire window, including its title bar, border, and other peripheral elements, and by a content rectangle that encloses just its content area.